# TypeScript Compiler API: How to get fully qualified name of type without absolute path?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to create a tool working on specific types using TypeScript's TypeChecker API. I need to uniquely identify specific types - like Angular's [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) from `@angular/platform-browser` package. I have following code to get fully qualified name of the type

```
let type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
let fqn = typeChecker.getFullyQualifiedName(type.getSymbol());
```

However, this returns name which contains absolute path to the `node_modules` directory, such as
`"/home/user/project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser".DomSanitizer`

I would like to remove the part which is project specific, to have only something like `"@angular/plaform-browser/platform-browser".DomSanitizer` . I would prefer to use TypeScript API rather than doing some string operations on this value, as I expect the API to be more robust.

Comment: What should be the behaviour in the (somewhat likely) case there are multiple copies of the API (e.g. two different versions of `lodash` being used by two dependents containing slightly different types)?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum good question. I would be ok to have the same fqn in such case.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this using the public API. From what I can see, you can use `typeChecker.symbolToString` to get just `DomSanitizer` (which is what `getFullyQualifiedName` uses internally), but then to get the module name the parent symbol is not available in the public API (`symbol.parent`) and I don't see a way to go from the resolved name to the original module name (only the opposite).

Comment: Regarding the Bounty: Assuming that there are no suitable methods in the API, I'd consider rewarding the bounty for any systematic exposition of how the various settings can influence the mapping from the original package names to the file paths (and then hope that this would be sufficient for mapping the file paths back to the package names)

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the project root is, you can use [NodeJS's `path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) method for this:

```js
import * as path from 'path'

const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
const fqn = typeChecker.getFullyQualifiedName(type.getSymbol());

const projectRoot = '/home/user/project/node_modules/'
const relativePath = path.relative(projectRoot, fqn)
console.log(relativePath) // should print @angular/plaform-browser/platform-browser.DomSanitizer
```

Comment: One addition to this solution - in theory `fqn` could be inside other `node_module` folder e.g. `/home/user/project/node_modules/other-project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser`, or even outside of project's root (because of nodejs lookup algorithm).